# Fixed and starts after scrolling with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I have 3 coloums , I want when I scroll down col 2 will be fixed and start scroll after offset top 100 and col 3 will be fixed and start scroll after offset top 200.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-5">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">2</div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQiIJ.png

Comment: you posted the same question 3 times now ...

Comment: In the mean time: What have you tried yourself? And why didn't it work?

Comment: i tried  this but didn't works https://www.bootply.com/8vHdIkVV5x#

Comment: <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-5" id="midCol1" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" >3</div>
</div>

/* custom theme */

.affix-top {
 top:60px;
    position:fixed;
}

/* custom theme */
    
#midCol.affix-top {
    position:fixed;
   margin-left:-18px;
   margin-right:10px;
}

#midCol.affix-bottom {
 position:static;
}

#midCol.affix {
    position:static;
}

@media (max-width:1190px) {
  .affix,.affix-top,#midCol.affix,#midCol.affix-top {
      position:static;
  }
}